problems with ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1 enviroment veriable
I have two simple nodes. I want the first node to publish topics only on the localhost, and the second node to subscribe to the topics published by the first node, perform some processing, and then publish the processed data over the LAN network. I don't want first node to publish data directly over LAN network. I have already tried configuring Fast DDS with .xml, but I need some help. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you!
